# Clipless MTB Shoes for wider feet

Tags: bike-fit, shoes

I have wider feet.  I would like to find a clipless shoe that is on the wider side.  What clipless shoes offer multiple widths?  What clipless shoes are naturally wide?

---

I currently just have (standard width) North-West clipless shoes.  If I leave them on the looser side, they are reasonably comfortable.

Other notes:

- Looking for something as stiff as possible.
- Mountain clipless not road clipless
- Keens are my go-to hiking shoe, because of their width.
- *As requested by batmat in the comments, my shoe size is 43 or 10*

Comment: It would help if you listed your foot size (My sneakers are US 13 or occasionally US 12) -- the selection will vary a lot on the higher and lower ends of normal foot sizes.

Comment: @Batman Updated question.

Answer (score 2):

To start, Keen makes a commuter bike sandal that is clipless, so you may look into that if you like the fit of Keens.  I know that Specialized makes wide sizes in their shoes as does Lake.  There may be others out there, but that is what I am immediately familiar with.

As far what to avoid, most of the European companies (especially the Italian companies like Sidi) tend toward a fit that is aimed at a narrower foot.  Sidi, makes a Mega option that is supposed to be wide (I believe), but I haven't ever seen a pair to try and the regular Sidis fit me horribly (I also have a wide foot).